# How to make this HTML input label

Tags: html, input

What is a concise way to have the HTML input label (i.e. the "Enter your password") go on top of the box like the way Gmail implements it? I have done some digging but have only found labels that go on the left of the input form, and is quite far from the what the image shows.

[image]

Comment: it's useful to know what you have already tried in order to solve the problem. Otherwise it may look like you're trying to get some homework done instead of putting some effort on it.

Answer (score 0):

The `transform` property is your friend. You can use `translateY` to move it upwards, and `scale` to shrink it down. Here's a useful link: [W3Schools transform](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp)

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of days' search, I found a pair of somewhat obscure HTML element, called `fieldset` and `lengend`, which are dedicated for this usecase. The `fieldset` gives rise to the box/outline, and the `lengend` produces the "Enter your password" description in the image of this question.

Demo below and see also the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset).

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Enter your password</legend>
  <input>
</fieldset>
```